# Check if two line segments intersect

Tags: geometry

I have a two line segments. Points at both ends of those segments are given by cooridnates (x, y, z).
What's more I know that those segments lie on the same plane given by a normal. How can I check if those segments intersect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found an answer here: http://paulbourke.net/geometry/pointlineplane/lineline.c.

Answer (score 1):

Since the segments are on the same plane, you can test whether they intersect by testing their projection onto one of the coordinate planes. The standard 2D test that does not compute the intersection point is described [here](https://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/91primitives/). Here is pseudo code:

```
ccw(a,b,c):
   return (b.x - a.x) * (c.y - a.y) - (c.x - a.x) * (b.y - a.y)

intersect(a,b):
   if (ccw(a.p, a.q, b.p) * ccw(a.p, a.q, b.q) > 0) return false
   if (ccw(b.p, b.q, a.p) * ccw(b.p, b.q, a.q) > 0) return false
   return true
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but ccw appears to use a left-handed coordinate system (take `a = (1, 0), b = (0, 0), c = (0, 1)`).

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an equation for these line segments?

The idea is that if they intersect:

a) since they are on the same plane, they both satisfy equation for a plane simultaneously

b) at the same time, if they intesect there would be point satisfying both equations of the line simultaneously.